# Joomla custom article fields

Tags: joomla

I'm looking to start trying some article layout overrides with new fields placed in the administration area, but really am having trouble finding help online that guides through the whole process. Unfortunately the most in-depth guides on the topic (including on joomla.org) are for 2.5 or below, but I'm looking to go with version 3 of course.

I want to eventually use the technique to add a variety of fields, but my first goal that I figured would be a good starting point was to make the 'full article image' linkable. What i mean by this, is when a user is editing an article in the administration area, when they go across to the 'images and links' tab, it could have a field for 'link' which would make the image linkable.

So far, I've copied  /administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php to: /administrator/templates/isis/html/com_content/article/edit.php

but not sure the best technique from here - I can edit existing fields but would like to know best practice to add a 'link' field and then render this is the article layout (template override would be used).

Thought, ideas? Be nice to document this well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a content plugin - take a look at [this question/answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-to-save-custom-fields-in-core-components/2397#2397) at joomla.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

To make the full article image linkable simply requires modifying the layouts using a layout override. or alternate/alternative layout. THat is instead of echoing the links and images separately echo them so they create a linked image.  No plugin needed. However for new fields you do need a plugin.